# Ionic - Dynamic Column for Picture gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page which shows list of images in a grid. Each picture has a constant height and width. When the user resizes the browser or loads the page, I want the number of images per row to be depending on the screen size. For larger screen sizes, the more images.
For now I tried this.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-3  *ngFor="let product of products">

            <ion-card>
                <ion-card-content>
                    <div (click)="OpenProductDetails(product.ProductId)">
                        <img src="{{product.MainMediaUrl}}" style="height:200px; width:200px; margin:auto; margin-top:15px" />                         
                    </div>

                </ion-card-content>

            </ion-card>

        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Now on page load, it is loading correctly, but as I change the browser size or I make portrait to landscape, it is still the same and not responsive.

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set breakpoints to your grid cols like this

```
<ion-col col-xs-3 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 *ngFor="let product of products">
```

- col-xs- sets col for `min-width: 0px` and forward.
- col-sm- sets col for `min-width: 576px` and forward.
- col-md- sets col for `min-width: 768px`and forward.
- col-lg- sets col for `min-width: 992px` and forward.
- col-xl- sets col for `min-width: 1200px` and forward.

Knowing this, if you set a col-md- it'll set the same number to cols lg and xl. Just see what's better for your problem, if in larger displays the image breaks then you can set a smaller number of columns when in `md`displays or larger.

Hope this helps.